# Message Prompt for user validation before closing the page or clicking back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am just curious to know, how to post a JavaScript validation message before closing a page (or before clicking the back button) if the user is still performing some editing in a text filed?

Facebook prompts with a browser validation message while chatting and a user tries to close the browser or the user clicks the back button. I know I can display a message by using `window.onbeforeunload` or `window.unload`.

But how do I determine the editing state client side? 
Or, if that edit state is controlled on the server side of the application, how do I send it to the client?

Answer (score 1):

JS:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    var editingBox = document.getElementById("editingbox");
    if(editingBox.val != "")
        if(!window.confirm("Are you sure you want to leave?"))
            return false;
}
```

HTML:

`<input type="text" id="editingbox"/>`

Comment: @AlexShilman You wouldn't but if there is text in the field then surely the user **is** typing (or has been). Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question :p

Comment: @AlexShilman Surely though if there's text in the input box then the user obviously still is editing and hasn't submitted - I don't see why you have to make an ajax call

Comment: Because the text won't appear in the box until the other user hits enter. Right?

Comment: @AlexShilman You are right, google chat will not prompt any message while closing the browser.

Comment: AFAIK you can check the value of an input field at any time, in fact I know you can, therefore I'd go with @user2521439 - at worst you could set a variable to have value 1 if onChange of the editable field and has length>0 then check if that variable has value before exiting the page

Answer (score 0):

Top level solution. On one user's side key up will make an ajax call, while setting an Editting field in the db or a key in mongodb. Then on your end you make an ajax call on window.onbeforeunload to see if user one is Editting.

Comment: Sorry but thats just bad. Think about it, FB have a like a billion users, so if 1% are chatting at the same time that's 10 million ajax calls per character typed just so they can display a message saying "don't go, you might not be finished yet!" Erm, no.

Comment: The way I understood the question is if you and I are chatting, how can I determin the Editting state of the chat input box of your browser window before I close my window browser.

Comment: OP clearly says "I am just curious to know, how to post a JavaScript validation message before closing a page (or before clicking the back button) if the user is still performing some editing in a text filed?" It doesn't mention other side status, apologies if I'm reading it wrong but not sure how I can be.